# How can I select elements based in part of data- attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors, contains

Can I use **contains:** in a selector to select all elements with a data- attribute or is there any other way of selecting **all** these elements?
For example all elements containing "NL" or "UK"

Comment: `[data-country*="NL"][data-country*="UK"]` [Attribute Contains Selector \[name*=”value”\]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: @Satpal in this case use `~` is better, you don't want to match `UKR` for example if using `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to match `UKR` for example if using `*`, so you should use `~` to find an exact match in a whitespace-separated list of words

> ### [attr~=value]
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly value.

Take a look at here (2 mins read)

> ### Attribute selectors
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```css
[data-country~="UK"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span data-country="USA UK CHN">USA UK CHN</span><br>
<span data-country="USA UK">USA UK</span><br>
<span data-country="UK USA">UK USA</span><br>
<span data-country="UK">UK</span><br>
<hr>
You dont want the following to be matching:<br>
<hr>
<span data-country="USA CHN">USA CHN</span><br>
<span data-country="USAUK">USAUK</span><br>
<span data-country="UKR">UKR</span>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? Selecting if the data does not contains a value? I try $('[data-country*!="All"]').hide();

Comment: @CarlosMartins `span[data-country]:not([data-country~="UK"])`. `span[data-country]` select all span with attribute data-country, `:not` filter all matching data-country that contain UK

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this too:

```
$('[data-country^="UK"]') {
  color: red;
});
```